# Initializing IBOutlet in ViewController at correct time

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a button which triggers below code:

```
let verificationLetterVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VerificationLetterViewController") as! VerificationLetterViewController
    verificationLetterVC.currentDocumentPartTitle = documentPart.title
    self.keychain["path"] = PDFGeneratorHelper.makePDF(verificationLetterVC.textView, fileName: "title")
```

Basically I'm trying to initialize viewController and set certain title for `currentDocumentPartTitle` to call certain textfile and set it to  verificationLetterVC's textview.

The problem occurs at `makePDF` method I made. makePDF method takes textView as a parameter. It renders the textView and returns PDF file with a name which was passed as a 2nd parameter.

Even if I initialize the viewcontroller, it says  `verificationLetterVC.textview` is nil. How can I solve this problem?

Here is `VerificationLetterViewController` class:

```
 class VerificationLetterViewController: UIViewController {
        @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
        var currentDocumentPartTitle: String!

     override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool){
           super.viewWillAppear(animated)
       //textview configuration
    }
```

Comment: `viewWillAppear` won't be called in this case as you aren't presenting the VC.  Where do you add `currentDocumentPartTitle` to the text view?

Answer (score 0):

> Even if I initialize the viewcontroller, it says  verificationLetterVC.textview is nil. How can I solve this problem?

You need to either connect the `textView` property to an actual text view in your storyboard, or, if instantiating the view controller yourself, set the `textView` property yourself after instantiating.

Comment: it is connected to actual text view in my storyboard. The only thing I'm doing is dynamically changing text in textview on different circumstances.